# vector bad throw alloc expetion even don't access any element

Tags: c++

I write the following code

```
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <cfloat>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;



vector< vector<double> > merge_sort(vector< vector<double> >& source, vector< vector<double> >& result){





}

int main(){

       vector < vector<double> >test;
       vector < vector<double> >temp;

    merge_sort(test, temp);

}
```

and to my exception,  the program shut down and I just get bad alloc expection and I don't know why, I even have not access any element.

Please tell me how to fix it.

Thx in advance.

Comment: I don't see any code there catching a bad_alloc exception.  How do you know that's what it does?  Please post the real code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Can you post some realistic code? Or are you really not returning anything?

Comment: You are not returning anything and so most likely when cleaning up the stack it is crashing

Comment: Oh, sorry about that, I just start to write and try to test the function prototype and agrument.

Comment: @KazDragon: You don't necessarily have to write your own catch blocks for exceptions to be reported: http://ideone.com/Di3ddR

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that your function has a return type but you're not returning anything. This gives you undefined behaviour. See §6.6.3:

> Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a `return` with no value; this results in undefined behavior in a value-returning function.

Comment: was just about to post that.

Comment: It is strange that this should not even compile, at least under Visual Studio.

Comment: @tacp It results in undefined behaviour. It can compile if it wants to. It can do whatever it likes. :)

Answer (score 2):

As I said in my comment since you are not actually returning anything, you now have undefined behavior. Most likely when trying to clean up the stack it is crashing.